# Continuous scroll with UIScrollView Xcode

Tags: xcode, view, uiscrollview, scrollview

How do I make a scroll view start over again?

IE: my `UIScrollView` is `1000px` wide. The user will swipe through the view to find a topic. When the user reaches the last topic (say topic 10) how do I have the `UIScrollView` start back at the beginning (topic 1) without having to scroll backwards?

So, the view will just continue in a circle forever, if the user wishes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that you are going to use:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

after you detect that user reaches the last topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a paging `UIScrollView` with topics as pages. The trick is to duplicate the end pages, and then when the user swipes to the last page in the scrollview (which is a duplicate of the first page) and the deceleration stops you want to change the content offset back to the first page.

When I needed to do this, I found [this post](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html). I used `setContentOffset` in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` rather than `scrollRectToVisible`, but either approach will work.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffsetOfLastTopic animated:NO];
    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == contentOffsetOfLastPage) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffsetOfFirstTopic animated:NO];
    }
}
```